# select all states of specific country using React JS

Tags: reactjs

My code is running properly but it is showing all the states of all countries and I don't want all the states I only want the states of the country which I have selected.
My api is-
[image]
Here is my code-

```
   <select name="state">
            <option>--Select state--</option>
            {
                state.map((person) => {
                    return(
                        person.data.map((data,ind) => {
                          return (
                            data.states.map((states, index) => {
                                return (  
                                  <option key={index}>{states.name}</option>
                                );
                              })
                          );
                        })
                    );
                  })
            }
               
        </select>
```

Comment: post the country select

Comment: I will take that from database because I have already asked user for the country and stored it in database.so I have stored that country in variable name country.